# Asset Pipeline in Ruby on Rails with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been having trouble using the Asset Pipeline. Although I read an excellent guide [here](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html) I still have trouble.

I'm trying a javascript solution for adding form elements "on the fly" from this [guide] (http://jyrkis-blogs.blogspot.com/2014/06/adding-fields-on-fly-with-ruby-on-rails.html#code4Div)

When I put the javascript into a `<script>` tag at the bottom of my page, everything works as expected. 
If I simply copy and paste the script into application.js the code also works.
However, when I try to move the code to `app/assets/javascripts/people.js` my site throws a Reference Error.

This is a similar problem to the questions on SO titled 'Ruby on Rails 3.1 RC1 Javascript Asset Pipeline Problem' (not enough rep for the link), but I only have one script, so the alphabetical solution doesn't help. Moving the file to vendor/assets/javascript also didn't help.

Application.js currently looks like:

```
This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
listed below.

Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.

It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
compiled file.

Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
about supported directives.

= require people.js
= require_tree .
```

Comment: have you require your `people.js` in the `application.js` after move code to `people.js`? Also show us related `application.rb` and `config/environments`

Comment: Are you putting the code into `app/assets/javascript` or `app/assets/javascripts` (notice plural)? The Asset Pipeline only checks the folder `javascripts` by default.

Comment: @ Зелёный I'm having trouble adding the application.js, SO seems to think the // is a link and requires more reputation.

Comment: omit `js` in the `people.js` restart the server and try again.

Comment: @RyanK I only have app/assets/javascripts - is app/assets/javascript created by default?

Comment: It should be plural, but in your question you have singular.

Comment: whoops - thanks for catching that

Comment: You shouldn't even need `require people`; `require_tree .` should pick up any js files in the same directory. Are you sure they're in the same directory? Is the "reference error" in the js console or Rails? When you look at sources in the developer toolbar, do you see the js you're trying to add?